# Incorrect format or out of bounds error while setting up schedule task

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create schedule task in PHP but I get an error.

```
$input = 'schtasks /create /tn testSendMail /tr "php\"D:\wamp64\www\testScheduler\SchedulerURL.php"" /sc once /st 11:00';
$input = escapeshellcmd($input);
echo $input;
$execution = exec($input." 2>&1",$output);
var_dump($execution);
var_dump($output);
```

When I execute this I get:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(93) "Erreur�: Le code XML de la t�che contient une valeur incorrectement format�e ou hors limites." [1]=> string(12) "(39,4):Task:" }
```

In English:

```
task XML code contains incorrect values format or is out of bounds
```

But when I execute this command line on terminal it creates a schedule task.
I searched but I found this nothing about this.

Comment: Did you try to exec your command out of php, does it work?

Comment: it work when i execute it directly in cmd

Comment: have you tried `$output = shell_exec($input." 2>&1");`  ?

Comment: i get exactly the same error with shell_exec() :(

Comment: i've tried to replace this : "php\"D:\wamp64\www\testScheduler\SchedulerURL.php"" by notepad.exe and it' doesn't work too ...

Comment: Run schtasks with the **/XML** like that `$input = 'schtasks /create /XML  ....`

Comment: that says that wait a value for /xml ? what values should i give ?

Comment: `schtasks [/XML xmlfile]` just to export the xml file and check if the xml syntax is correct

Comment: error : option /xml can only be use with /s /u /p /ru /rp /f /it /tn that's what i have

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from this part of your command:

```
"php\"D:\wamp64\www\testScheduler\SchedulerURL.php""
```

there are some problems while escaping characters.

Thus, I would go with a:

```
"php \"D:\\wamp64\\www\\testScheduler\\SchedulerURL.php\""
```

An other advice, prefer to go with magic constants like **DIR** inspite of using hand written absolute path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `__DIR__` is available _inside_ PHP scripts - but this is the command line.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! unfortunaly i've tried your solutions and it doesn't work. i really don't understand this problem. if i try to launch php -i command instead of schtasks it works. So as well, i've tried to launch with notepad.exe instead of my php script and it failed too, but it should work ^^'

Answer (score 0):

ok, if someone have the same problem, i got it.
it's not code problem, the problem is that i run this on IIS, i've tried it on wamp and it was working.
i will comment this when i will find the solution.

Comment: ok i got it ! it was a problem with IIS right. if you have the same problem just think to add /RU and /RP arguments